# How to only stage line deletions in a changeset?

Tags: git

I've been coding in a particular file for too long without committing, and I've ended up with a situation where I want to commit feature (A) that removes a line of code. But, in my file, I also have work on feature (B) that adds a new line of code in the place of the code removed by feature (A).

In order to commit feature (A), I want to commit the change that deletes the original line. I *don't* want to commit the change that adds the new line from feature (B).

How do I just commit the deletion of the line, and leave the addition as an unstaged change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`git add --edit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt---edit) to [edit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_editing_patches) the diff. Run `git add --edit`, search for the relevant line and delete the line that contains the code you added for B. It should start with `+`. You should see the line that you want to remove for A and it should start with `-` (keep it).

Editing the diff shouldn't modify your working directory, but I'd make a backup of the file just in case!

Comment: While `git add --edit` works well in this case, it's worth mentioning that `git add --patch` is more general: It walks you interactively through all the hunks, allowing you to decide whether you want to stage it or not, and giving you the option to edit any individual hunk. When you have 20 hunks in a file, 10 of which you need, 8 that you don't need, and 2 that you actually need to edit, `git add --patch` is the command you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a GitKraken answer: When you click a file and see the changes in hunk view, you can add each changed line sparately by clicking the "+" sign that appears right between the line numbers:

[image: GitKraken: stage single line in hunk view]

Klicking this in front of the deleted line will stage it and leave all other changes in the shown file as unstaged.

Comment: This is only the case for "simple" deletions. When a change is both a deletion and an addition, the two become associated and adding one also adds the other, as shown in this sequence: https://imgur.com/a/3XvAJ0l